# Android emulator console in ubuntu not showing network command

Tags: console, android-emulator, ubuntu-14.04, telnet

I'm connecting to android emulator console with telnet

When I try to to change network status I don't find network command

When I type help the following commands appear to me

> ```
> help|h|?         print a list of commands
> crash            crash the emulator instance
> kill             kill the emulator instance
> quit|exit        quit control session
> redir            manage port redirections
> power            power related commands
> event            simulate hardware events
> avd              control virtual device execution
> finger           manage emulator fingerprint
> geo              Geo-location commands
> sms              SMS related commands
> cdma             CDMA related commands
> gsm              GSM related commands
> rotate           rotate the screen by 90 degrees
> try 'help <command>' for command-specific help
> ```

In windows one more command named network appears, how can I solve this?